# Como listar um Array com .map()?

Tags: javascript

Como posso listar um Array usando .map()? no exemplo abaixo, consegui listar usando um loop for, como posso obter o mesmo resultado usando um .map()?

```js
var students = [
    {
        name: 'Anna',
        grade: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        grade: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'Maria',
        grade: 9
    }
];
for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
    console.log(students[i].name);
    console.log(students[i].grade);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas para passar por todos e mostrar, geralmente é utilizado o [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

No caso do [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) ele poderia ser utilizado, no entanto ele geralmente é utilizado para criar um novo array resultante da alteração do array em questão.

No caso do `forEach` e do `map`, ele é chamado com uma função, sendo que o primeiro parâmetro é o "ponteiro", ou valor atual, o segundo parâmetro é o índice do array em questão (parâmetro opcional), e o terceiro parâmetro (também opcional) é o array em si, podendo ser assim:

```
students.map(function (student, index, arr) {
  console.log(student.name);
  console.log(student.grade);
  console.log(index);
  console.log(arr);
});

students.forEach(function (student, index, arr) {
  console.log(student.name);
  console.log(student.grade);
  console.log(index);
  console.log(arr);
});
```

Em modo ES6, sendo que neste caso não é necessário os parâmetro opcionais, apenas para listar os dados ficaria assim, com `forEach` e `map`:

```js
var students = [
    {
        name: 'Anna',
        grade: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        grade: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'Maria',
        grade: 9
    }
];
// for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
//    console.log(students[i].name);
//    console.log(students[i].grade);
//}
students.forEach(student => {
  console.log(student.name);
  console.log(student.grade);
});
students.map(student => {
  console.log(student.name);
  console.log(student.grade);
});
```