# Alterar os dados do array que vem da api

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Tenho uma dúvida em uma aplicação em **react native** gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

Como faço para incrementar um novo item no array que vem da api.

O `array` da api hoje retorna assim:

```
data:[{ id:1, name:'product01'}, {id:2, name:'product02' }];
```

Eu gostaria de colocar **status** dentro deste array para cada item. Como posso fazer?

Comment: utilizar o `.map` e fazer um novo `array`

Comment: um exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/460562/javascript-map

Answer (score 2):

Criar um novo `array` com [map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-map-method/#:%7E:text=The%20map%20%28%29%20method%20in%20JavaScript%20creates%20an,and%20calling%20function%20on%20every%20element%20of%20array.) que vai passar por todos os itens e [Object.assign](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/object-assign-in-javascript#:%7E:text=Object.assign%20%28%29%20in%20JavaScript%3F%20This%20method%20is%20used,properties%20and%20values%20copied%20from%20the%20target%20object.) que pode adicionar elementos novos em cada objeto, ***exemplo***:

```js
const data = [{ id:1, name:'product01'}, {id:2, name:'product02' }];

const changeData = 
  data.map(function(item) {
    return Object.assign({}, item, { status: true });
  });
  

console.log(changeData);
```

***Boa leitura:***

- [Qual é a diferença entre Object.assign e spread operator?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/477895/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-object-assign-e-spread-operator)
- [Como listar um Array com .map()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302111/como-listar-um-array-com-map)
- [O que é map / reduce?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195126/o-que-%c3%a9-map-reduce)

Comment: Muito obrigado, foi util pra mim.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do colega @novic pode utilizar o `forEach()`, conforme abaixo:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, name: 'product01' }, { id: 2, name: 'product02'}];
data.forEach(item => item = Object.assign(item, { status: true }));
console.log(data);
```